# angular material pass table row data to menu items

Tags: angular, angular-material

i need pass data from table row element to menu but it send only `undefined` data. i use `matMenuTriggerData` for that like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="execute">
   <th mat-header-cell fxFlex="8%" fxLayoutAlign="start center" *matHeaderCellDef></th>
   <td mat-cell fxFlex="8%" fxLayoutAlign="start center" *matCellDef="let element">
       <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" [matMenuTriggerData]="element">
           <i class="material-icons" style="color: #368852">cloud_download</i>
       </button>
   </td>
</ng-container>
```

and menu:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-aliasMenuItems="element">
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="cl(aliasMenuItems)">
    <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
....
</mat-menu>
```

if you want to see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-pass-rowdata-menu)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You should pass data something like this
>   `[matMenuTriggerData]="{element: element}"`, If you want all the items. Because when you are
>   accessing a variable like `let-aliasMenuItems="element"`, you are
>   trying to access variable's value not variable

If you would like to access variable's value which is `priorityIndex` then you can do something like this

`[matMenuTriggerData]="element"`

and

`let-aliasMenuItems="priorityIndex"`

[Working stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-pass-rowdata-menu-zkd6ds)

Answer (score 0):

In contentable

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="execute">
   <th mat-header-cell fxFlex="8%" fxLayoutAlign="start center" *matHeaderCellDef></th>
   <td mat-cell fxFlex="8%" fxLayoutAlign="start center" *matCellDef="let element">
       <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" [matMenuTriggerData]="{element: element}">
           <i class="material-icons" style="color: #368852">cloud_download</i>
       </button>
   </td>
</ng-container>
```

and menu:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <ng-template matMenuContent let-aliasMenuItems="element">
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="cl(aliasMenuItems)">
    <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
....
</mat-menu>
```